# create UUIDs for unique key-value pairs while preserving dict integrity

Tags: python, dictionary, uuid

I have a list of dicts

`[{'fruit': 'apple', 'color' : 'green', 'UUID':''}, {'fruit': 'guava', 'color': 'green','UUID':''}, {'fruit': 'pear', 'color': 'green','UUID':''},{'fruit':'banana','color':'yellow'}]`

and I'm trying to create UUIDs by color. For example, I'd want apple, guava, and pear, which all have the key-value pair `'color' : 'green'` to share a UUID, while 'banana', which has the key-value pair `'color' : 'yellow'` to have its own UUID.

It seems like I'd want to do some sort of groupby-esque operation on the list of dicts and then apply the UUID generator. Is this the right way to think about it? Or is there a smarter/easier/generally less dumb way of doing this? I'm having a hard time visualizing this, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uuidmap = {}
for d in L:
  if d['color'] not in uuidmap:
    uuidmap[d['color']] = generateUUID()
  d['UUID'] = uuidmap[d['color']]
```